# Update record using laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-4, laravel-8

I have a question,
I  have a form (view)  and after submit it saves to the db.
one of the records is id.
when I open the form again for that ID and will press submit again
what will happened it will update the record? or try to create a new record and fail since id is primary key?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to update record based on it's `id` then you could do this

```
public function update($request)
{
    $user = User::firstOrNew([
                'id' => $request->id
            ]);
    $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $user->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $user->save();
}
```

It will find a record with that `id`, if none was found then create a new record with that `id`. This is just for example but you need to `validate` every request before update/insert.

Answer (score 0):

so it depends on your controllers etc if you have a updateController with the correct code it can be updated but you would also need a edit method as well, If you could share your code it will be easier to say what would happen instead of guessing

Comment: I need to write the controller, so I try to understand if when I write save(), it will remove the previous values or just try to do insert

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required|unique:categories',
        ]);

        $category = new Category();
        $category->name = $request->name;
        $category->slug = str_slug($request->name);
        $category->save();
        Toastr::success('Category Successfully Save','Success');
        return redirect()->route('admin.category.index');

    }
```